# How to absolutely position a div right outside the main one?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

Let's say I have some code like this:

```css
.a {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  position: relative;
}

.b {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  right: -33px;
}

.c {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: -88px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">hello</div>
  <div class="c">testing longer</div>
</div>
```

If you run the snippet you'll see the desired behavior, where both `b` and `c` are positioned on the right edge of the `a` element.

The only issue I'm having is that on my website `b` and `c` have dynamic contents (I don't know what they'll be ahead of time). Is it possible to somehow modify the `right` property of both `b` and `c` such that I don't have to hardcode the value in and they will still be positioned on the outer edge of `a`?

Comment: left:100% instead of right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

- `left: 100%` or
- `right: 0` and `transform: translateX(100%)`

**Example:**

```css
.a {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  position: relative;
}

.b, .c {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.b {
  top: 30%;
}

.c {
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">hello</div>
  <div class="c">testing longer</div>
</div>
```

I'd probably go a step further and wrap `.b` and `.c` with another element so that you can get rid of hardcoding `top` too.

```css
.a {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  position: relative;
}

.d {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(100%, -50%);
}

.c {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="d">
    <div class="b">hello</div>
    <div class="c">testing longer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, of course! Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help, @RyanPeschel 